# A word/phrase to describe cooperation of scientists who lived in different times

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, phrase-requests

Let's imagine that Scientist A works in some field but obviously they don't do everything from scratch but rather built upon past discoveries of, for example, Scientist B who lived 200 years before Scientist A was born.

I'm looking for a word or a phrase that would describe this situation. I thought of "intergenerational cooperation" but wouldn't the word "intergenerational" imply that it refers to cooperation between of e.g. a 20-year-old and a 80-year-old living in the same times? Can I use this phrase in this context?

Do you have any beter ideas for a phrase?

Comment: "Transgenerational", that means acting across multiple generations, may be a better choice than *intergenerational*.

Comment: "Cooperation" means working together. You can't work together with a dead person.

Comment: @Rathony -- Odd, there's a raft of recent movies and TV shows that say you can.

Comment: @HotLicks The dead persons appear in the movies or shows, don't they?

Comment: @Rathony - You're right about "cooperation", so with what word would you replace it?

Answer (score 3):

If I have seen further it is because I have stood upon the shoulders of giants. Or words to that effect. Think it was Newton who said it originally, but it's a widely echoed sentiment and particularly relevant to science.

Comment: http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/i/isaacnewto135885.html

Answer (score 0):

[Redefining the wheel:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel#Related_phrases)

> Redefining the wheel is the practice of coming up with new and often abstruse ways of describing things when the existing way of describing them was perfectly adequate.